# How to remove the last word and print the remaining path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the value of the actual variable to be printed like this.

**Variable value**

```
rootdir = '/home/runner/TestP1'
```

**Required value to be printed**

```
/home/runner
```

I used the code like this

```
hello = rootdir.split("/")[1]
print(hello)
```

**Given value**

```
TestP1
```

but I want to remove just the last word from that string and print the remaining path.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) function from os.path

> Return the directory name of pathname path. This is the first element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split().

```
>>> from os.path import dirname
>>> rootdir = '/home/runner/TestP1'
>>> dirname(rootdir)
'/home/runner'
```

Answer (score 0):

`split()` gives a list of elements after separating the string by `/`.

So, you need to take all elements till the last and re-join:

```
hello = rootdir.split("/")[:-1]
hello = '/'.join(hello)
print(hello)
```

Use `rsplit()` instead and split only till one `/` from right:

```
hello = rootdir.rsplit("/", 1)[0]
print(hello)
```

Further, if you are trying to extract the directory name, instead use @sayse's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsplit (for spliting from the right side) and put number of max splits equal to 1. like this:

```
rootdir = '/home/runner/TestP1'
hello = rootdir.rsplit("/", 1)[0]
print(hello)
```

Output:

[image]